# How to get max value from a table with pivoted data or from all datatable columns

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a pivoted query that returns the count of events in a table (matrix) that compares week day vs time of day:

```
;WITH [pivotData] as
(
    SELECT  
        DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [Jc].[Fecha]) as [Day],
        DATEPART(HOUR, [Jc].[Fecha]) as [Hour],
        [Jc].[ID] as [ID]
    FROM [dbo].[Jornadas_Cronograma] [Jc]
    WHERE 
        ([Jc].[IdEstadoGeneral] = 1)
)
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            [Day] 
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Domingo'       
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Lunes'        
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Martes'        
            WHEN 4 THEN 'Miércoles'       
            WHEN 5 THEN 'Jueves'        
            WHEN 6 THEN 'Viernes'        
            WHEN 7 THEN 'Sábado' 
        END AS [Dia],
        [0] AS [00:00],
        [1] AS [01:00],
        [2] AS [02:00],
        [3] AS [03:00],
        [4] AS [04:00],
        [5] AS [05:00],
        [6] AS [06:00],
        [7] AS [07:00],
        [8] AS [08:00],
        [9] AS [09:00],
        [10] AS [10:00],
        [11] AS [11:00],
        [12] AS [12:00],
        [13] AS [13:00],
        [14] AS [14:00],
        [15] AS [15:00],
        [16] AS [16:00],
        [17] AS [17:00],
        [18] AS [18:00],
        [19] AS [19:00],
        [20] AS [20:00],
        [21] AS [21:00],
        [22] AS [22:00],
        [23] AS [23:00]
    FROM [pivotData]
        PIVOT
            (
                COUNT([ID]) FOR [Hour] 
                IN 
                (
                    [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23]
                )
            ) AS [pivoted]
    ORDER BY
        [Day];
```

This will return this result:

[image]

I need to get the max value from all the columns (in this example it will be 93, for Wednesday 08:00) and store it in a variable, integer, or so.. to operate it in the front end

In my app, I will render this info to a DataTable.

I've tried to iterate through each column of the datatable and store the .max value into a list, but it's not working as expected, and I'm stalled at this point.

I'm guessing the best approach will be in C# rather than SQL, but I'm a beginner, and I have no more ideas!

I iterated through columns, try to store the values in a list, and then try to get the max value within that list. In this example I'm iterating on columns 00:00 and 06:00, for testing purposes:

```
        gvMapaHoras.DataSource = traerMapa();
        gvMapaHoras.DataBind();

        List<List<int>> miLista = new List<List<int>>();
        
        int mxTotal = 0;
        
        foreach (GridViewRow fila in gvMapaHoras.Rows)
        {

            Literal lt00 = (Literal)fila.FindControl("lt00");
            int vl00 = Convert.ToInt32(lt00.Text);

            Literal lt06 = (Literal)fila.FindControl("lt06");
            int vl06 = Convert.ToInt32(lt06.Text);

            miLista.Add(new List<int> { vl00, vl06 });

        }

        mxTotal = miLista.Max();
```

But my error at this point is that I can't relate a List into a integer.

To populate the gridview I created a class:

```
 protected DataTable traerMapa()
    {

        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conx2 = new SqlConnection(enchufe0))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(spQuerySel2, conx2))
            {
                cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2))
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt2);
                }
            }
        }

        return dt2;

    }
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution in C# or SQL Server?

Comment: As @Dale K mentionned, please say, whether you are looking for an SQL solution or a C#, in the latter please provide the code you have - also a version of your C# code, that failed to _I've tried to iterate through each column of the datatable and store the .max value into a list, but it's not working as expected, and I'm stalled at this point._

Comment: Do you want both the maximum value in each column *and* the day of the week that happened?

Comment: @DaleK ok, noted, I just wanted to demonstrate the resulting table as clearly as possible.

Comment: @BitLauncher I think the best approach will be on C#, but I'm blocked so I would really appreciate if you have a better solution. I edited my question.

Comment: @epaezr thats what we want too, and formatted text is much clearer than an image. Also for a [mre] you only need to show us the relevant columns - not the entire table. That will also make it clearer.

Comment: Performance wise, getting the max value will most likely be faster in SQL as its designed for that sort of thing. However you need to pick and tag and target your question at the technology you want your solution in, otherwise its not a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SQL SERVER approach

Here we

1. Aggregate the data in the 1st CTE `pivotData`
2. Calculate the `maxValue` in `cteMaxVal`
3. Then we simply apply the `maxValue` to the pivoted results via a `CROSS JOIN`

**Example**

```
;WITH [pivotData] as
(
    SELECT  
        DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [Jc].[Fecha]) as [Day],
        DATEPART(HOUR, [Jc].[Fecha]) as [Hour],
        Count(*) as Cnt
    FROM  [dbo].[Jornadas_Cronograma] [Jc]
    WHERE ([Jc].[IdEstadoGeneral] = 1)
    GROUP BY DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [Jc].[Fecha]),
             DATEPART(HOUR, [Jc].[Fecha])
), cteMaxVal as (
    Select MaxVal=max(Cnt) from [pivotData]
)
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            [Day] 
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Domingo'       
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Lunes'        
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Martes'        
            WHEN 4 THEN 'Miércoles'       
            WHEN 5 THEN 'Jueves'        
            WHEN 6 THEN 'Viernes'        
            WHEN 7 THEN 'Sábado' 
        END AS [Dia],
        [0] AS [00:00],
        [1] AS [01:00],
        [2] AS [02:00],
        [3] AS [03:00],
        [4] AS [04:00],
        [5] AS [05:00],
        [6] AS [06:00],
        [7] AS [07:00],
        [8] AS [08:00],
        [9] AS [09:00],
        [10] AS [10:00],
        [11] AS [11:00],
        [12] AS [12:00],
        [13] AS [13:00],
        [14] AS [14:00],
        [15] AS [15:00],
        [16] AS [16:00],
        [17] AS [17:00],
        [18] AS [18:00],
        [19] AS [19:00],
        [20] AS [20:00],
        [21] AS [21:00],
        [22] AS [22:00],
        [23] AS [23:00],
        MaxVal
    FROM [pivotData]
        PIVOT
            (
                sum(Cnt) FOR [Hour] 
                IN 
                (
                    [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23]
                )
            ) AS [pivoted]
    Cross JOIN cteMaxVal
    ORDER BY
        [Day];
```